# Practice Exam Questions

Tags: c, struct, malloc, c-strings

This is a practice exam question that I am having some difficulty with:

```
struct bodytp // Is there an error?
{
    char *name; // If so, fix the error.
    int len;
};

main()  
{
      struct bodytp person;
      keepname(&person , "Waterman");
      printf("%s\n", person.name); 
}

void keepname(struct bodytp *onept, const char *last)
{
    int len;
    char *tpt;
    for ( len = 0; last[len] != '\0'; )
    len++;
    char name[len+1];
    for ( tpt = name; *tpt++ = *last++; )
    ;
    onept->name = name;
    onept->len = len;
}
```

I have determined that there is an error, as when I run it, I get garbage output from printf. I have also determined that `person`'s `name` is indeed "Waterman" after the keepname function call. I have tried dereferencing `person.name` to `person -> name`, changing the problem from a stack-based question to a heap-based question by eliminating the ampersand operator and malloc-ing the struct, but nothing worked. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `onept->name = name;` here, you are assigning a local variable's address whose lifetime is over after the function call returns.

Comment: If it answers, it should be an answer @BlueMoon :)

Comment: len is not really the problem as it's initialized in the loop...

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should indent `len++;` after `for ( len = 0; last[len] != '\0'; )`. Otherwise your code is unreadable. The same for the `;` after `for ( tpt = name; *tpt++ = *last++; )`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. How is `onept->name = name;` not permanently copying `name`'s value into `onept`'s `name`?

Comment: @tdark `onept->name = name` copied the **pointer** to `name`. But as soon as you exit from the `keepname` function, `name` will most likely be overwritten. You cannot return pointers to local variables because local variables will be overwritten as soon as thes go out of scope. You need to allocate memory with `malloc`instead. This memory will persist until you free it.

Comment: "hanging the problem from a stack-based question to a heap-based question by eliminating the ampersand operator and malloc-ing the struct, but nothing worked" - you need that, you just applied it in the wrong place. as others mentioned, you need it for `char name[len+1];`

Comment: Oh! Ok. I get it now. So does that mean the only way to fix this is to change `char name[len + 1]` to `char *name = (char *) malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));` and **then** `onept -> name = name;`?

Comment: The `(char *)` casting isn't needed?

Comment: `keepname()` should be prototyped or defined before use in `main()`.

Comment: `int len;` should be `size_t len;` to cope with _very_ long strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an error?

```
struct bodytp // Is there an error?
{
    char *name; // If so, fix the error.
    int len;

};
```

No there is no error. It is a valid structure definition.

Now errors follow.:)

Function main shall be declared as

```
int main( void )
```

Though it is not an error nevertheless it would be better that before the function call there woud be the function prototype

```
keepname(&person , "Waterman");
```

The program has undefined behaviour because there is an assignment of a pointer to the structure by the address of a local array that will be destroyed after exiting the function

```
void keepname(struct bodytp *onept, const char *last)
{
    //...
    char name[len+1];
    //...
    onept->name = name;
    //...
}
```

The valid function could be defined like

```
void keepname(struct bodytp *onept, const char *last)
{
    int len = 0;
    char *tpt;

    while ( last[len] != '\0' ) len++;

    char *name = malloc( len + 1 );

    for ( tpt = name; *tpt++ = *last++; ) ;

    onept->name = name;
    onept->len = len;
}
```

In this case you have to free the alocated memory in main.

Take into account that you coud use standard C functions `strlen` and `strcpy` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the memory for the name in the heap.

```
void keepname(struct bodytp *onept, const char *last)
{
    int len;
    char *tpt;
    for ( len = 0; last[len] != '\0';len++);
    char *name=malloc(len+1);
    onept->name = name;
    onept->len = len;
    for ( ; *name++ = *last++ ; ); 
}
```

Comment: There is an end condition: `*tpt++ = *last++`. The return value of this statement is the assigned value. The moment the `\0` is encountered, it evaluates as `false` and the loop stops.